# Building a "fat jar" in ant using ivy without copying the jars to a lib directory

Tags: ant, ivy

I'm interesting in building a "fat jar" in my Java project where Ivy resolves the dependencies.  It seems wasteful to me to have to copy the referenced jar files from the ivy cache to the local project, so I'd like to avoid doing that.  I found a solution that works, but wonder if there is a slightly simpler way.  In the code below what I thought would be easiest is for the zipfileset line to work, but it does not - the jars are included in the built jar file, but they are not expanded.  If instead I use the  section it works properly, but seems like a bit of extra fuss.  Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
<target depends="clean, build" name="jar">
    <ivy:cachefileset setid="Ping.runclasspath" conf="default" />
    <jar destfile="dist/Ping.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="build"/>
        <zipfileset refid="Ping.runclasspath"/>      <--- this does NOT work
        <restrict>                                   <--- this DOES work
           <name name="**/*.class"/>
           <archives>
              <zips>
                 <fileset refid="Ping.runclasspath"/>
              </zips>
           </archives>
        </restrict>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you experimented with [zipgroupfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html#zipgroupfileset)?  I don't know if it would actually work in your example, but it seems to have a similar purpose for existence.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do the same thing in one of my ant projects. Chris' suggestion of using `zipgroupfileset` works:

```
<target depends="clean, build" name="jar">
    <ivy:cachefileset setid="Ping.runclasspath" conf="default" />
    <jar destfile="dist/Ping.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="build"/>
        <zipgroupfileset refid="Ping.runclasspath"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```